# Javacc regular expression

Tags: regex, javacc

I am trying to write a parser for a subset of G-Code using Javacc, but have run into problems with the regular expressions. When I use the symbols `"^"` and `"$"` to match the beginning and end of the string I get errors, if i remove them it runs but regex is incorrect.

For example I want the lexer to accept the string `"G01"` or `"G02"` but without `^` and `$` it would allow `"G01G02"`.

```
options {
    STATIC = true;
}

PARSER_BEGIN(Parser)
    class Parser {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Parser lexan = new Parser(System.in);
            try {
                lexan.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            System.out.println("Finished Lexical Analysis");
        } // END main
    } // END class
PARSER_END(Parser)

// TOKENS
// Ignore all whitespace
SKIP:{" " | "\t" | "\n" | "\r"}

// Declare tokens 
TOKEN:{<G0X: ^"G0"["1", "2"]$>}

void start():
{}
{
    (<G0X> {System.out.println("\G0X\n");})+
}
```

What regular expression would I need to get this to work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Tried this, then i get the following error:  org.javacc.parser.ParseException: Encountered " "(" "( "  <ACT_TOK> "\" "" at line 36, column 31.

Comment: So each token "G01" or "G02" must be on a line by itself with no white space before or after?  Or do you want to allow white space before the "G" and after the "1" or "2"?

Answer (score 2):

JavaCC does not support the ^ and $ that are common with other reg ex tools. Instead it supports something more powerful (and harder to use) lexical states. You can (and should) read about them in the JavaCC documentation and FAQ.

I don't know G-Code, nor can I find a standard quickly, but from a quick look at examples and tutorials I'll make some assumptions.

- Each line is empty, a statement, or a percent sign by itself, or a comment.
- Each statement is a sequence of statement tokens.
- Statement tokens are codes, axes, numbers.
- Spaces and tabs are allowed anywhere except inside a token that isn't a comment.
- One comment per line at the start or the end or both (with possible statements or tabs before or after.

Approach: I'd treat newlines and comments as non skipped tokens and deal with them at the grammatical level. This means you don't actually need to use lexical states.

Lexical part:

```
SKIP:{" " | "\t" }

TOKEN: {
    <NEWLINE: "\n" | "\r" | "\n\r" >
|   <PERCENT: "%">
|   <COMMENT: "(" [^")"]* ")"
|   <G0X: ^"G0"["1", "2"]$>
|   <AXIS: "X" | "Y" | "Z">
|   <NUMBER: ... >
}
```

Grammatical part:  Here's I'll use informal notation, as JavaCC is rather noisy

```
Program --> PERCENT NEWLINE (Line)* PERCENT NEWLINE
Line --> COMMENT (Statement)? NEWLINE | Statement (COMMENT)? NEWLINE | NEWLINE
Statement --> G0X (AXIS NUMBER)*  // I'm really just guessing here.
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont have enough reputation to comment, so i will write this down as a possible solution.

I barely ever got to try JavaCC, but I did mess up with regex a lot.

Anyhow -

It's really hard to understand what your regex is trying to do, but as far as i understand, You are trying to find instances of

```
G0(Number here)
```

And you are struggling with the use of $ and ^.

The possible alternative is to try and specify what are you looking for after the "G0" in the regex itself instead of leaving a bunch of wildcards.

and for that case, i might have a solution for you.

**Solution**:

Regex:

```
G0[0-9a-zA-Z]
```

All that i've done is just add the parenthesises - which in regex, specify a range of characters that might be accepted. This way, you recieve all the instances of "G0" with a single number/letter after them.

Have a nice day :)

Comment: I want to use the ^ and $ to limit the string to one instance of the regex. The solution you gave allows me to input a string such as "G01G02" and it would be accepted.

Comment: Not really. the parenthesises limit that; Look at this : http://oi57.tinypic.com/141l05d.jpg


Source: http://www.regexr.com/

Comment: They are brackets, not parentheses. Besides, the OP was not asking how to match `G01` or `G02`, he was asking how to make sure just one was on the line, which yours does not do.